# play different clips via GetKeyDown in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have the Animator with parameters of bool type. 
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgMlr.jpg)

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            anum.SetBool("ca", true);
          //  anum.SetBool("ca", false);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            anum.SetBool("cv", true);
        } }
```

but only one first keydown is working.what 2 do?

UPD: I try with integer parameter,but it also doesnt work

```
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
         {
             anum.SetInteger("letter", 1);   
             print("1111111111111111");
         }

         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
         {
             anum.SetInteger("letter", 2);
             print("22222222222222");     
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set "ca" false, it is always true so animator can never turn to letterA.Also need to set "cv" false when 'S' is not pressed.

  ```
       void Update()
       {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
          {
              anum.SetBool("ca", true);

          }
          else 
          { 
             anum.SetBool("ca", false);
           }

          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
          {
              anum.SetBool("cv", true);
          }
          else 
          { 
               anum.SetBool("cv", false);
           }
   }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
void Update()
     {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            anum.SetBool("cv", false);
            anum.SetBool("ca", true);

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            anum.SetBool("ca", false);
            anum.SetBool("cv", true);
        }
 }
```

And also double check if your application is not exploding or giving RED error in console after pressing First Key.

Comment: Well, input code is just fine. Please check your "anum" entity, either it is able to do so or not

Comment: public Animator anum;

    public Animator anum;
    void Start()
    {anum = GetComponent<Animator>();}